# Different substitutions in First order logic?

Tags: logic, substitution

In First order logic the substitution

```
F{x1 / s1}{x2 / s2} ...{xn / sn}
```

can be different from

```
F{x1 / s1, x2 / s2, ... xn / sn}
```

How can these substitutions can be different? Can someone explain such a substitution to me along with an example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If `n`=2, and `s1` were an expression containing `x2`, then the second substitution would result in an expression containing `x2` while the first would not.